# Where can i find new Firebase Analytics BigQuery Export Scheme sample data?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

Firebase Analytics's BigQuery Export schema changed.
https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?visit_id=1-636660162514047959-3257228354&rd=1&hl=en

The previous version of the schema, google provides sample data in `firebase-analytics-sample-data` projects.

Is there the current version of it?

Answer (score 1):

The new sample dataset can be found [here](https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/dataset/firebase-public-project:analytics_153293282). [This help center article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7030014?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) links to it.

Answer (score -2):

You can find the new schema [Here](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?visit_id=1-636660162514047959-3257228354&rd=1&hl=en)